# WS: Hide file name's substring when displayed in tabs and in project file browser

Tags: intellij-idea, tabs, ide, webstorm

While doing Angular 2 development, there's this "kinda-unspoken-of" convention to suffix each filename with its type - it can be `component`, `module`, etc.

However, the filenames, when viewed in Webstorm's tabs and project file browser, become a little too long.

I'm looking for a way to hide a substring of the file name, that is, the file's type part.

So, effectively, `Modal.component.ts` becomes `Modal.ts` when displayed in the open file tabs and in project file browser.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can save you precious space is to hide filename extensions. You can tell file type from the icon anyway. Go to:

> Settings → Editor → General → Editor Tabs

And then

> Hide file extension in editor tabs

[image]

However, you may consider hiding tabs altogether. Many users do that as you can navigate through recent files much faster using keyboard shortcuts (such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>) and tabs just take precious space.

Comment: Although this may be a solution of sorts, I'd still largely prefer hiding a defined substring in the editor tabs. Come to think of it, I may hide the extensions as you suggest and then, given potentially limited customization options for WS regarding file name display in the tabs, I may either make a new convention for NG2 file suffixes, smth along the lines of `component -> comp`, `service -> serv`, `module -> mod`. Or get rid of this convention altogether as it provides little benefit because `service` suffix can be replaced with `Api` suffix, components - no suffix, modules - `Mod`.

Comment: Unfortunately as far as i know there is no solution to hide a substring, you would probably need to write a custom plugin for that. Personally, I got rid of tabs altogether, which saves even more space -  see this post: http://hadihariri.com/2014/06/24/no-tabs-in-intellij-idea/

Comment: That's unfortunate. I'll probably write a IntelliJ plugin myself in the upcoming 2 weeks and post it here as an answer myself. Couldn't find an existing plugin that would do this.